# Configurable products overselling

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, sales

I have a series of clothing lines setup as configurable products, with sizes created as the associated simple products.

Occasionally we will over sell a single simple product, but it is always the last item to sell that over sells. i.e. we have sold out of every other size except for a single size 6 item. That size 6 will possibly oversell, so it appears that the stock item isn't being deducted for the final item, or it isn't being set to out of stock.

What is the best way to start investigating this? Where should I be looking? Has anyone seen this issue before? Would this have anything to do with the cron job?

Answer (score 0):

Standard behavior is as follows (others will correct me if I'm wrong):

1. The item option shouldn't be displayed at all if it's not available.
2. The product's stock item should be checked when being added to the cart.
3. The checkout process should validate stock quantities as well.

`Mage_Checkout_CartController::addAction()` is how products are added to cart via the product page (among others). Start there, and step through the code. You'll find yourself stepping to `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setQty()`, which dispatches `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` event, which is consumed by  `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkQuoteItemQty()` - that's where the stock is checked.

Comment: Is it possible that a plugin could be overwriting the standard behaviour?